# PervasiveSQL CONCAT not working in LIKE statement

Tags: sql, sql-like, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to build a dynamic LIKE statement, where the last 2 digits of the current year is passed into the LIKE part.

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM "ALLE" AS v
WHERE
(v.VMT != '' AND
v.VMT LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('ID_', RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2)), '%') OR
v.VMT LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT('ID_', RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2)) )
```

CONCAT() in PSQL allows only 2 params.

I tried different things like:

1. CAST() the CONCAT with char
2. Put parenthesis around the CONCAT
3. Use WITH statement, what's not supported by PSQL so I tried a CROSS JOIN to feed in the strings from a plain select statement
4. Using the CONCAT/RIGHT function etc. in a stored procedure doesn't look like going to work either

Link to the docs: https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/sqlref%2Fsqlref.LIKE.htm%23

I guess this problem only applies to PervasiveSQL.
Somehow I need to pre-define both strings to feed them later into the LIKE part. But how?

Comment: From what I can tell, your CONCAT statements do have only 2 parameters - so what is the actually issue/error that you are facing? Does it run but just not produce the output you are expecting?  Assuming they're not erroring, if you put your CONCAT functions into a temporary SELECT statement you should be able to see what they are actually producing

Comment: I’d be concerned you have an or without ()s around it so the first statement and second statement or just the third statement need to be true seems fishy. Do you need ()s after the and around the or statements?

Comment: Try using || to concat values instead…?  You could also try and build them in a select of a cross join provided the cross join only has 1 record returned…and then use the columns generated as the where clause criteria

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Pervasive / Actian supports the `CONCAT` in a `LIKE` clause.  I tried a very simple statement:

```
SELECT * from T1 where C1 like concat('ID','test')
```

and I got a Syntax Error with the error indicating a problem between the CONCAT and the parenthesis.  Something like:

```
select * from T1 where C1 like concat<< ??? >>('ID','test')
```

Using the `CONCAT` in a `WHERE` Clause with an = worked.  Something like

```
select * from T1 where C1 = concat('ID','test')
```

I would suggest contacting Actian and opening a defect with them.